# An example of non-empty regular language for which a DFA with single accepting state doesn't exist

Tags: proof-explanation, automata

> Let $C$-type language be a regular language iff exists a deterministic finite automaton (DFA) $A$ which has a single accepting state such that $L=L(A)$. An example of a regular non-empty language which is **not** of $C$-type is $L=\{1,10\}$.

This is the proof:

> Suppose that $L$ is a $C$-type language, that is a DFA exists: $A=\big(\sum, Q, q_0, \{q_f\}, \delta\big)$ which accepts the language $L$.
>
> Then $\delta(q_0,1)=q_f$ and $\delta(q_0,10)=q_f$.
>
> Therefore $q_f=\delta(q_0,10)=\delta(\delta(q_0,1),0)=\delta(q_f,0)$.
>
> Since $\delta(q_f,0)=q_f$ then $\delta(q_0,100)=\delta(\delta(q_0,10),0)=\delta(q_f,0)=q_f$ so $100\in L$ in contradiction to the given details.

According to my intuition the DFA looks like along these lines:

[image]

I do understand that $100$ is also part of $L$ but I as far as I see the DFA has a single accepting state $q_f$ as is the definition of $C$-type language. It doesn't have more than one accepting state. So why is this a contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Since $\delta(q_f,0)=q_f$ then $\delta(q_0,100)=\delta(\delta(q_0,10),0)=\delta(q_f,0)=q_f$ **so $100\in L$ in contradiction to the given details**.

By definition, $L = \{1, 10\}$.

If $L$ is a $C$-type language, $100 \in L$.

Therefore $L$ is not a $C$-type language.

Comment: Does my drawing accurately describe the DFA from the example? If yes it has only accepting state doesn't it? (the double circle)

Comment: Sort-of. It's actually an NFA because it doesn't have a total function from (state, input) to next state. But the point is that already, with the transitions it does have, you can show that the language it accepts is **not** $L$.

Comment: But it has only one double circle (accepting state). What makes it no $L$ graphically? The fact that there're two arrows that go into $q_f$ circle?

Comment: The fact that if you go $\to 1 \to 0 \to 0 \to$ you end up in an accepting state.

Comment: So when they "single accepting state" this means that there're no circular transitions?

Comment: Single accepting state means the set of final states is a singleton. Now, if your question is "how to characterize C-type languages", you should ask this as a separate question.