# How to characterize a regular language for which exists a DFA which has a single accepting state?

Tags: proof-explanation, automata

This question is based off [An example of non-empty regular language for which a DFA with single accepting state doesn't exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978033/an-example-of-non-empty-regular-language-for-which-a-dfa-with-single-accepting-s/2978135?noredirect=1#comment6146648_2978135).

> Let $C$-type language be a regular language iff exists a deterministic finite automaton (DFA) $A$ which has a single accepting state such that $L=L(A)$. An example of a regular non-empty language which is **not** of $C$-type is $L=\{1,10\}$.

I don't understand what single accepting state means. According to my intuition the DFA for this example would look like:

[image]

Indeed there's a single accepting state here (double circle) so I don't understand why this DFA doesn't have a single accepting state.

Comment: The automaton you drew does not have $L(A) = \{1, 10\}$, it has $L(A) = 10^*$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn the comment into an answer:

The automaton you drew does indeed only have a single accepting state,
but the language of the automaton is $10^*$, not $\{1,10\}$.
For example, your automaton accepts $100$, which is not in $\{1,10\}$.